# linux 64bit libjvm.so : file format not recognized

Tags: java, linux, 64-bit

when i use javavm on my linux(64bit), 
i get the error: .../amd64/server/libjvm.so:file not recognized: file fromat not recognized.

i can't search any helpful info about this.

Linking JNI lib on Linux with Java 7 JDK

```
g++ -L$MYJDK/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm touch.o -o testjdk
/tc_work/dsd/testjdk7/jdk1.7.0_02/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized

file $MYJDK/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so 
/tc_work/dsd/testjdk7/jdk1.7.0_02/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped

nm $MYJDK/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so 
nm: /tc_work/dsd/testjdk7/jdk1.7.0_02/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so: File format not recognized
```

Comment: Do you pass -D64 parameter to starting java process?

Comment: In my experience, it much easier to call JNI from Java than call Java from C. (relatively speaking)

Comment: @Andreas `uname -a`:Linux suse_64_dev173 2.6.16.60-0.21-TENCENT64-domU-101130 #7 SMP Tue Nov 30 07:19:57 CST 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @ErdinçTaşkın, how to pass -D64 parameter to java process. i use C to call java, when i `make`, i get the error.

Comment: @ErdinçTaşkın I do not think that this is an issue of "-D" - "-D" is passed to the java launcher to define which JVM (32 or 64 bit) to use, but in this case the libraries are not recognized by the toolchain when linking against the libjvm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you came across this bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7152237, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619513/linking-jni-lib-on-linux-with-java-7-jdk. I suggest to upgrade your toolchain (g++) to a more recent version, if possible.